# In Angular2 I have an ngFor and want to orderby 1 field

Tags: angular

In Angular2 I have an ngFor and want to orderby 1 field but without building a custom pipe.

Are there any built in ones I could use?

**This is my code:**

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of listOfMessages" [ngClass]="{unread: item.hasUnreadMessages}">
```

I want to order by item.hasUnreadMessages.

But I want the simplest way to do this.

I'm using html5 with angular2 and typescript

**My attempt:**

```
  this.listOfMessages = this.listOfMessages.sort((item1:any, item2:any): boolean => this.compareByBool(item1, item2, "hasUnreadMessages"));


  compareByBool = (item1: any, item2: any, fieldName: any): any =>{
      return (item1[fieldName] === item2[fieldName] ? 0 : (item1[fieldName] ? -1 : 1));
  }
```

If this is true: hasUnreadMessages then item should be at top of array

Comment: As you probably noted, angular2 deliberately doesn't have an orderBy pipe (see: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html). They recommend you hold a secondary array of sorted elements and display them. Will that work for you?

Comment: yeh hows best to do that? do you have a lodash example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement your own sorting and then do

```
this.sortedItem = this.items.sort((item1, item2): number => compareByNumber(item1, item2, fieldName));
```

or

```
this.sortedItems = this.items.sort((item1, item2): number => compareByString(item1, item2, fieldName));
```

depending on your field type

```
function compareByNumber(item1, item2, fieldName){
  return item1[fieldName] - item2[fieldName];
}
function compareByString(item1, item2, fieldName){
  return (item1[fieldName] < item2[fieldName] ? -1 : (item1[fieldName] === item2[fieldName] ? 0 : 1));
}

function compareByBool(item1, item2, fieldName){
  return (item1[fieldName] === item2[fieldName] ? 0 : (item1[fieldName] ? -1 : 1));
}
```

Comment: do you have one for compare boolean?

Comment: Added to the answer. Though note that sort that has lots of 'equal' values might take longer

Comment: Can you give an example of the input and output? Also, consider adding a print log in the function and trace it.

Comment: just updated my question with my attempt using your code

Comment: Thx. I need data. What data failed to sort?

Comment: And the result is not boolean but number

Comment: hasUnreadMessages is a boolean and I need all the objects that have it as true to be top of the array

Comment: Does it group them just in the wrong order? If it does, swap the -1 and the 1 in the result

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use a pipe since it's a decision by Angular team. There were too many troubles with performance that everyone blamed on Angular, which was only partially correct. So they made a choice not to include it and do not recommend using custom pipes for it.

More about it in the official docs [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe-). It also explains what you can do instead. Basically write your own ordering method like `orderedListOfMessages()` and do it in typescript/javascript inside your component.

But remember it will happen very very often, so if you know that underlying data has not changed, you can instead add a new variable `orderedListOfMessages` and update it once right after the data is updated.

So the first approach is simple, but should be used with caution (only very simple and fast, like 5-20 elements maybe).

The second approach is not too complicated, but required more effort. You can be sure it won't overload page on mouse move though.

This very simple snippet seems to work fine for boolean comparison in js:

```
boolArray.sort(function(item1, item2){ return item1 ? 0 : 1});
```

Comment: Thanks for the information on this. Do you have a lodash example of how to orderby 1 field type for my array?

Comment: You don't need lodash. Use Array.sort((e) => e.hasUnreadMessages) or something. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: I have added a simple sorting for js to the answer. You can work from there to do the same with ts.